# Why does SCRAM authentication fail in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have set scram-sha-256 authentication in pg_hba.conf, but from psql authencation fails with message "FATAL:  password authentication failed for user". I submit password in the scram-sha-256 format. Is this right?
What can be the problem?

Comment: Did you reload PostgreSQL after changing hba file? Did you make sure that the entry used is the scram-sha one?

Comment: I have checked the database. All the passwords are in the scram-sha format. Yes, I have reloaded the database server.

Comment: What do you mean that you submit a password in the scram format?  Generally you "submit" the password to the client in plaintext, the client then uses that password to negotiate the authentication with the server.  What do you see in the server's log file?

Comment: Very likely, your PostgreSQL client software needs an upgrade.

Comment: 1) What version of Postgres server? 2) What version of `psql`? 3) At this point is safer to have the password setting being `md5` per [Password auth](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-password.html): *To ease transition from the md5 method to the newer SCRAM method, if md5 is specified as a method in pg_hba.conf but the user's password on the server is encrypted for SCRAM (see below), then SCRAM-based authentication will automatically be chosen instead.*. 3) No you supply the plain text version of the password to `psql`.

Comment: The Postgres version is 14.7. The version of psql is the same. If I supply password in PSQL and other programs in plain text, everything is OK. Supplying encrypted passwords in PHP does not work either. I thought I could store encrypted passwords to supply them from PHP and other programs. Can I? Or I should always supply them in plain text?

Comment: I understood. I should always submit a password in plain text.